# How to get one output table from select in while-loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edited to live up to the rules here. Sorry about my first attempt.

I got the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData(
    [Time] [time](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('01:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('02:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('02:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('03:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('03:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('03:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('04:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('04:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('04:00:00')
INSERT INTO SampleData([Time]) VALUES ('04:00:00')
GO
```

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 1

WHILE (@Counter <= 4)
BEGIN
    SELECT Count([Time]) AS OrdersAmount
        FROM SampleData
        WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, [Time]) = @Counter

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

This is the result of the query:

```
OrdersAmount
1
-----
OrdersAmount
2
-----
OrdersAmount
3
-----
OrdersAmount
4
```

So 4 seperate tables. What I need is one table, with alle values in it, on each their own row, like this:

```
OrdersAmount
1
2
3
4
```

I tried with cte and declaring a temp table, but I just can't make it work.

Comment: What is "RPA"?  What results do you want?  What actually *is* your question?

Comment: Sorry, RPA is Robotics Process Automation. So basically a "robot" pressing buttons for you in a certain order to get a specifik result. My question is how I can loop through my select and get the desired output in one table

Comment: . . I don't see the desired output in the query.  I see results from a current query and then lots and lots of explanation.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need an Hours table to join and group against. You can create this using a `VALUES` constructor:**

```sql
SELECT
    Count(*) AS OrdersAmount
FROM (VALUES 
    (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)
) AS v(Hour)

LEFT JOIN [FLX].[dbo].[NDA_SAP_Bestillinger]
 ON v.Hour = DATEPART(hour, PromisedPickupTime)
   AND PromisedPickupDate >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
   AND PromisedPickupDate < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AS datetime)
GROUP BY v.Hour;
```

What is going on here is that we start with a filter by the current date.

Then we join a constructed Hours table against the hour-part of the date. Because it is on the left-side of a `LEFT JOIN`, we now have all the hours whether or not there is any value in that hour. We can now group by it.

---

Note the correct method to compare to a date range: a half-open interval `>= AND <`

Do not use `YEAR\MONTH` etc in join and filter predicates, as indexes cannot be used for this.

Comment: I had to edit the v.Hour = HOUR(PromisedPickupDate) to v.Hour = DATEPART(HOUR, PromisedPickupTime), but then it worked. That's amazing. Now I have to figure out how you made that work. Thank you so much

Comment: I've tested it pretty thoroughly now, and while it does work really well, there is a slight issue, where it will not create an entry if there is no orders. In my current dataset I have no orders at 3am. This query simply skips that then

Comment: Yeah forgot that was why I wanted an Hours table in the first place. Have fixed now with a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Again thank you. Yes that does make sense, both the part why you wanted a table (which I could just make) and the left join. For some reason, is returns 1 in the 3am output which it skipped before because it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the data so can't test.

But if I get your problem right, this should work for you.

```
select PromisedPickupDt = cast(PromisedPickupDate as date), 
        [Hour] = datepart(hour, PromisedPickupDate), 
        HourlyAmount = sum(OrdersAmount) 
from [FLX].[dbo].[NDA_SAP_Bestillinger]
where cast(PromisedPickupDate as date) = cast(getdate() as date) 
group by cast(PromisedPickupDate as date), datepart(hour, PromisedPickupDate)
```