# Get one output table from select in while-loop without counting

Tags: sql-server, select, while-loop

The table `purchase` contains:

```
row    supplier | type | marker | price
       --------------------------------

1 ....   ABC    |  A   |   0    | 3.50
2 ....   ABC    |  B   |   0    | 4.40
3 ....   ABC    |  B   |   0    | 5.50
4 ....   ABC    |  C   |   1    | 8.70
5 ....   ABC    |  C   |   0    | 9.00

6 ....   DEF    |  A   |   0    | 3.80
7 ....   DEF    |  A   |   0    | 5.10
8 ....   DEF    |  D   |   0    | 9.20

9 ....   GHI    |  E   |   0    | 2.80
10 ...   GHI    |  E   |   0    | 3.30
11 ...   GHI    |  E   |   1    | 4.10
12 ...   GHI    |  E   |   0    | 5.40
13 ...   GHI    |  F   |   0    | 9.90
```

A query should deliver entries for `type` which fulfill the following conditions:

- from `supplier` only which has at least one dataset with `marker = 1`
- for `price` which is smaller than `price` with `marker = 1` for that specific `supplier`

This applies to the rows 1, 2, 3, 9 and 10.

My attempt is (following [Nakeuri's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702149/looping-through-select-result-set-in-sql) general guideline):

```
DECLARE @supplier CHAR(3), @price FLOAT
DECLARE CurName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT SUPPLIER, PRICE
    FROM PURCHASE
    WHERE MARKER = 1
OPEN CurName
FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @supplier, @price
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT TYPE
        FROM PURCHASE
        WHERE SUPPLIER = @supplier AND PRICE < @price
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @supplier, @price
    END
CLOSE CurName
DEALLOCATE CurName
```

This results in individual outputs per supplier:

```
type    (for supplier ABC)
----
 A
 B

type    (for supplier GHI)
----
 E
```

I'd need one output table:

```
type
----
 A
 B
 E
```

How do I have to edit the query for a merge of the two outputs into one output? The suggestion for [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66693759/how-to-get-one-output-table-from-select-in-while-loop) can not be applied as my case is not a counting operation.

System:

- Product: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)
- Operating System: Windows Server 2022 Standard, Version 21H2

Comment: Why are you looping at all here, why not write a proper set-based query?

Comment: Also aside, `@Price FLOAT` is 100% incorrect.

Comment: I imagine the instructor is telling you to use a while-loop?...but really, no one would.

Answer (score 0):

The set-based query you need (rather than a RBAR approach) is as follows:

```
select *
from t
cross apply(
  select Min(price) MinPrice
  from t t2
  where t2.Supplier = t.Supplier and t2.marker = 1
)m
where t.Price < MinPrice;
```

This shows you the rows identified, and from this you can return your required results with

```
select distinct type from...
```

See a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IQT5yvBN)

Result:

[image]

Comment: why not just approve the edit? distinct

Comment: I think it would be useful to the OP to also realise the intermediate step of identifying the rows speciified that meet the criteria

Comment: Ah, ok, fair enough. OP already knows about that.  They have a "SELECT DISTINCT TYPE" in their example and they clearly show the output required.

Comment: If i understand the OP correctly, there might be multiple rows with marker = 1 per supplier. The old solution might generate multiple rows per supplier / row. I might be overthinking this too :D

Comment: @siggemannen I think Stu has that covered with min(price). Gets the lowest price of all marker=1

Comment: @NickAbbot thanks - and sure I realise they know `distinct type` which is why I didn't actually have that originally, what they *need* is how a query can find the desired rows without the procedural looping method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function here

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.type
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      MIN(CASE WHEN t.marker = 1 THEN t.price END) OVER
         (PARTITION BY t.supplier) AS MinPrice
    FROM t
) t
WHERE t.Price < t.MinPrice;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/9FEn9RHu)